# Liquibase, how to set default schema programmatically in Java

Tags: java, postgresql, liquibase

I am trying to run Liquibase in my appliction code. The problem is that new table ale created in public schema, how can I point liquibase to different schema in my Postgres.

```
    Liquibase liquibase = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    try {

        connection = DB.getConnection();
        liquibase = new Liquibase(CHANGELOG_FILE, new FileSystemResourceAccessor(), new JdbcConnection(connection));

        //change default schema here

        liquibase.update(STAGE);

    } catch (LiquibaseException e) {

    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.rollback();
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bad code.  Catch blocks should never be empty.  You should rollback in the catch block and log it.  You never commit.  You always rollback in the finally block, so none of your changes will ever stick.

Comment: Cool thank you, but it is just proof of concept. I am more interested in answer to my original question than carring about rest...

Comment: "None of your changes will ever stick" - this is pertinent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the schema in the changeset using `schemaName` attribute. So you don't need to write it programaticaly.

[Here](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/index.html) you can review official documentation for every refactor/changeset you can do. Take a while and see how you can specify what schema is the target for every refactor.

For example, add column changeset:

```
<changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="addColumn-example">
  <addColumn catalogName="cat"
        schemaName="public"
        tableName="person">
    <column name="address" type="varchar(255)"/>
  </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: That is neat and all, but what do I do when I need to set the liquibaseSchemaName property? *Edit:* Nevermind, I found it: `database.setLiquibaseSchemaName("schema_name");` does it!

Answer (score 5):

This can be done using the [`liqubase.database.Database::setDefaultSchema`](http://www.liquibase.org/javadoc/liquibase/database/Database.html#setDefaultSchemaName(java.lang.String)) method. For example:

```
        val dbUrl = "jdbc:h2:~/aviary-db/dev;MODE=MySQL;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=false;IGNORECASE=TRUE;INIT=create schema if not exists aviary;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;TRACE_LEVEL_SYSTEM_OUT=2"
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, user, password)
        val dbConnection = JdbcConnection(conn)
        val database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(dbConnection)
        database.defaultSchemaName = "schema_name"
        val liquibase = Liquibase("db/db-changelog.xml", ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database)
        liquibase.update("")
```

It's also worth noting that you can use `setLiquibaseSchemaName` to decide which schema liquibase will use for it's internal tables `databasechangelog` and `databasechangeloglock`.